# How to run two suite files in parallel in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

```xml
<suite name="Parallel_Run" parallel="true">
  <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="suite1.xml"/>
    <suite-file path="suite2.xml"/>
  </suite-files>
</suite>
```

I am using above XML file to run two xml files but it is running sequentially, I tried putting `parallel="true"` as well but the same output

I want to run both XML files in parallel.